# HTML Agility Pack, create new line in HTML file

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

```
Dim codice As String
Dim doc As New HtmlDocument
Dim coll As HtmlNodeCollection
Dim node As HtmlNode
Dim nuovo As HtmlNode

codice = "<li><a href=""#"" onclick=""ApriClass('" + D_Clas.SafeFileName + "')"" title="""">� " + T_ClasNome.Text + "</a></li>"
doc.Load("classifica.html")
coll = doc.GetElementbyId("subnavi").SelectNodes("ul")
node = coll.Last
nuovo = HtmlNode.CreateNode(codice)
node.AppendChild(nuovo)
doc.Save("classifica.html")
```

This add a line of HTML in "codice" at a specified position, but I've noticed that everytime it writes to my HTML file it doesn't go to a new line, so it will write:

```
**(1st item)**<li><a href="#" onclick="ApriClass('classificagiocatori3.htm')" title="">� 3 Class</a></li>**(2nd item)**<li><a href="#" onclick="ApriClass('classificagiocatori.htm')" title="">� classificagioca.0tori.htm</a></li>
```

How can I go to a new line in the HTML file for a more confortable view?

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can try something like this.

```
var newLineNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("\r\n");
var nuovo = HtmlNode.CreateNode(codice);
node.AppendChild(newLineNode);
node.AppendChild(nuovo);
node.AppendChild(newLineNode);
```