# Add newline in HTML source code using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I am modifying a HTML file using the HTML Agility Pack.

Here is an example on a HTML file containing tables:

```
Dim document As New HtmlDocument
Dim tables As Array

document.Load(path_html)

Dim div1 As HtmlNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div></div>")
Dim div2 As HtmlNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div></div>")

tables = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").ToArray()

For Each tr As HtmlNode In tables.Descendants("tr").ToArray
   tr.AppendChild(div1)
   tr.AppendChild(div2)
Next

document.save(path_html)
```

And here is the result in the HTML file:

```
<div></div><div></div>
```

What I would like is:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

I think this should be implemented by default as it makes my HTML file unclear.

I saw this question (which is my exact issue) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263838/html-agility-pack-new-line-in-html-file) but the answer is not working for me (maybe because of VB.NET and the answer is C#).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you added the `newLineNode`? This would be `Dim newLineNode As HtmlNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("\r\n")`. Then you would use like `tr.AppendChild(div1)`...`tr.AppendChild(newLineNode)`...`tr.AppendChild(div2)`

Comment: I tried this but it adds '\r\n' in my HTML, it's not going back to line.

Comment: `tables.Descendants("tr").ToArray` throws up a compile error for me. Maybe it's this that's the problem? Can you provide your initial HTML within the question or a least a sample of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't written any `vb.net` in a ***long*** time, so first tried this in `C#`:

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
var div = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div></div>");
var newline = HtmlNode.CreateNode("\r\n");
div.AppendChild(newline);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    div.AppendChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div></div>"));
    div.AppendChild(newline);
}
document.DocumentNode.AppendChild(div);
Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentNode.WriteTo());
```

Works great - the output:

```
<div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Then thought, "*no way....it can't be*" - note the commented lines:

```
Dim document = New HtmlDocument()
Dim div = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div></div>")
' this writes the literal string...
Dim newline = HtmlNode.CreateNode("\r\n")
' this works!
' Dim newline = HtmlNode.CreateNode(Environment.NewLine)
div.AppendChild(newline)
For i = 1 To 2
    div.AppendChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div></div>"))
    div.AppendChild(newline)
Next
document.DocumentNode.AppendChild(div)
Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentNode.WriteTo())
```

Unfortunately it is so, and probably why the [question you linked to was not marked answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263838) - the output:

```
<div>\r\n<div></div>\r\n<div></div>\r\n</div>
```

Finally, instead of using the newline string as `\r\n` tried `Environment.NewLine`, which *does* work and outputs:

```
<div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Works either way in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9941684/6375113) you would need to add in a node that represents a Carriage Return (`\r`) and a Line Feed (`\n`):

```
Dim newLineNode As HtmlNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("\r\n")
```

Based on your comment:

> I tried this but it adds '\r\n' in my HTML, it's not going back to line.

You've already tried this and instead it prints the string literal "\r\n". I too have managed to replicate this issue.

Instead look at using `<br>` tag which is a line break:

```
Dim newLineNode As HtmlNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<br>")
```

Based on your example code, your code would look something like this:

```
Dim newLineNode As HtmlNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<br>")

For Each tr As HtmlNode In tables.Descendants("tr").ToArray
   tr.AppendChild(div1)
   tr.AppendChild(newLineNode)
   tr.AppendChild(div2)
Next
```

However `tables.Descendants("tr").ToArray` did provide a compile error for me. As that's out of the scope of this question and you haven't raised it as an issue I'll make an assumption that it works for you.